# AWS CDK: how to deploy resources to different accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Is it possible to deploy resources to two different AWS accounts using CDK?

As a simple example, imagine 2 resources that are linked (2 different IAM roles, perhaps), that need to be deployed to accounts `accountA` and `accountB`.  They are linked, so their lifecycles should be tied together (i.e. they are created and destroyed at the same time and I shouldn't have to run two deployment actions).  I'd like to be able to specify at deployment time where the resources go, not at synthesis time.

This requirement is easily achieved using Terraform (by means of two different `provisioner` definitions).  How do I achieve this using CDK?  Can this be achieved within a single stack, or is the CDK model that of one stack per target account?  What does a simple example look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. you need to pass environment config object to stack props.

**From the docs:**

> Each Stack instance in your AWS CDK app is explicitly or implicitly
> associated with an environment (env). An environment is the target AWS
> account and AWS Region into which the stack is intended to be
> deployed.

**Usage:**

```js
const envEU  = { account: '2383838383', region: 'eu-west-1' };
const envUSA = { account: '8373873873', region: 'us-west-2' };

new MyFirstStack(app, 'first-stack-us', { env: envUSA, encryption: false });
new MyFirstStack(app, 'first-stack-eu', { env: envEU, encryption: true  });
```

More info [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/environments.html).

In case you want to deploy 2 different resources within the same stack to 2 different accounts, this is not supported yet.
You would need to create different stack for each resource and pass the environment object accordingly.

Comment: If you are using two different accounts, how do you run the bootstrap command so it identifies credentials for both accounts?

Comment: You can add a trust between accounts so you can deploy from one account to another. It's part of the bootstrapping and is explained here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/bootstrapping.html